# Neo4j OGM updation deletes other attributes of entity

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am using neo4j OGM for CRUD operations. But when I use  session.save(entity, 0) where entity has only id and updated attribute, other attributes associated with entity are deleted fro neo4j entity.

For example Object car has id, name and year.

If I just set id and year in entity, name attribute will be deleted, which i donot want.

I donot want to fetch and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preserve existing values in the database, you have to load first the data.
This is the way all OGM / ORM work.

To update just specific attributes you can use a dedicated cypher query.